# How can my react app can return for non-existing page status 404 for document?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

everyone!
I've added my web-site to searching system, and it's retruned error like "Your non-existing pages don't return status 404". But I can't uderstand how do return this status.

I try to find solve this problem, but all what I get it's "React App just front for website. it can't return other status except 200"

Comment: You tagged [tag:express] do you use server rendering?

Answer (score 1):

React runs on the client, so in the browser. Not being able to send 404 status codes for pages that are missing is a common problem with single-page applications, such as react.

You cannot return a http status code from a react application that only runs in the browser.
Most probably you are running a static web server like nginx or apache that delivers your react application, consisting of a html file that includes a script tag, to the client (with a status code 200).

You can display a page that displays "Not found" to the user in react but if you want to send a real 404 http status code, you need to do it from server side. If this is a requirement for your application, then most likely you should be looking into "server side rendering" of your react application. There are several technologies that can make this easier for you, like NextJS or Astro.